# Performance testing of PMML application

Tags: performance-testing, pmml

Could you let me know the best practices for conducting performance testing of my PMML application which is based on JPMML evaluator and/or our own PMML sort of scoring engine. I found some sample PMML and corresponding test data at http://dmg.org/pmml/pmml_examples/index.html. But I am looking for very large data (which represent the actual customer transaction dataset). Also, I come to know the JPMML 1.2.6 is around 10x faster w.r.t. 1.2 but consumes some extra memory. What are the best practices to verify it on large data set (GBs of dataset)

Comment: Have you considered posting this question directly to JPMML mailing list? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jpmml

Comment: I have posted my query in the JPMML goggle group as well.